# Suggesting the related records

Tags: workbench, endeca, endeca-workbench

We are trying to display related results on details page in endeca.
Upon clicking on any record on category(record listing) page, we want to display record id's having same parent id of the clicked record.

Example:

```
Record id    Parent id Property1 Property2
100           100      vcx       jhk  
101           100      abc       def
102           100      xyz       cvb
103           110      hki       qer
```

If I perform search for record id = 101, I should get one result and if I navigate to that record, I want to display the details of record id = 101 and also I want to list the record id =100 and record id=102 as related results. Because all these three records having same parent id (i.e 100).

We are trying to implement this with the help of assembler-context.xml modification so that it will reflect in assembler API as our application is using assembler API to render the results.

I am sorry if it is a naive question as I am new to endeca :). Please help.

Regards,

Mohan.

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

1. Make parent id as a dimension.
2. Use record filters (Nr).

Comment: Hi Krish, Thanks for your inputs.If I use Nr filter, it will list down all the records having that dimension but I want to list the records (just a record title) having the same parent id when I am in a detail page of any record.For example, If I am looking at the details of record 101, I want to show the user that there are related articles to this and those are Rid=100 and Rid=102 beacuse all these 3 records share same parent id.

Comment: Can't you use: `&Nr=parentId:100` ?

Comment: If I add &Nr=parentId:100, it is listing all three products in the record listing/category page but if I navigate to details page by clicking on any record, I am able to see the properties of only one record. But I want to show the links of other 2 products(So that if user clicks on any of them, I can display the properties of that record) along with the details of product which was clicked.

Comment: Design your details page like a record listing/category page so that it fetches all the three records in single query (Use _Navigation Query_ (N=) instead of _Record Query_ (R=)).  Then display the appropriate record as the main record and use other 2 records in the related results.